# Regular Expression for a++ or a-- or ++a or --a

Tags: javascript, regex

Can anyone help with regular expression for post increment-decrements or pre increment-decrements. i.e., it must return true for a++, a-- , ++a, --a.

Comment: @SZenC i'm trying like this /[\w][\+|\-]{2}|[\+|\-]{2}[\w]+/g; but it's returning true for a+++, +++a, a---,---a

Comment: You cannot parse progamming languages with regexes. Tell us more about what you're trying to do so that we can suggest a right tool for this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can also do it without escaping, using character sets:

```
/(a[+-][+-]|[+-][+-]a)/gm
```

Or if `a+-` is not allowed:

```
/^(a[+][+]|a[-][-]|[+][+]a|[-][-]a)$/gm
```

Comment: it is returning true for a++b, a++ also

Comment: Ok, I've modified it accordingly.

Comment: a+- or a-+ would work here, it needs back references I think.

Comment: So `a+-` is ok then?

Comment: I've edited the answer with a version that doesn't match on `a+-`.

Answer (score 2):

`+` and `-` have special meanings in a regular expression. (But `-` only does within a *character class* which we won't need). So you need to *escape* the `+` if you want to match them as possible values. You do that using a backslash.

So `a\+\+|a--|\+\+a|--a` is a simple regular expression that would do the job. You could use this directly in Javascript if you surround it with `/` and `/`, which denotes a regular expression literal.

Depending on your matcher, you might need `^(a\+\+|a--|\+\+a|--a)$`.

Comment: it is returning true for a+,+a,a-,-a also
I want only [\w]++ or ++[\w] or  [\w]-- or --[\w] these return true

Comment: Not in my tester it doesn't. Did you implement it correctly? I think you still have a single slash in there somewhere. I've put the whole thing in the answer.

Comment: var str = "a--";
    var patt = /a\\+\\+|a\\-\\-|\\+\\+a|\\-\\-a/;
    var res = patt.test(str); 

this is what i tested. It is returning false now for all cases

Comment: @LokeshReddy: when using a regexp literal `/.../` there's no need to double the slashes.

Comment: @Bathsheba even though it is not working. It returns true for a++b

Comment: Are you still doubling up the slashes? You shouldn't be.

Comment: `-` doesn't have special meaning outside a character class (`[...]`) so you don't need to escape it.

Comment: Yet another helpful comment which I've plagiarised. My conscious is increasing in opaqueness.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
/a[+-]{2}\s|\s[+-]{2}a/g;
```

As commented by @RoToRa, you do not need `[\+|\-]`.

```js
var regex = /a[+|-]{2}\s|\s[+|-]{2}a/g;

var str = "hello ++a this is a++ a test for --a and a-- but not for a--a";

console.log(str.replace(regex, " * "))
```

Output

```
hello  *  this is  *  a test for  *  and  *  but not for  * a
```

Comment: As in? A special case is not working or entire this is not working?

Comment: during replace, it works fine. I'm using test() method in js. it needs to return true only if above cases (words followed by ++ or --,  ++ or -- followed by words) but your pattern returns true even if we use a++b

Comment: `[\+|\-]` means either `+`, `|` or `-`. Also `+` isn't a special character inside a character class, neither is `-` if it's the last character so you just need `[+-]`.

Comment: @LokeshReddy I have updated my answer. Hope it helps

Comment: Leave out the `|` too, or it will match that character.

Comment: @SZenC I support you, but in this case it is valid. Outputting to console. `:)`

Comment: @Rajesh Thanks for the reject. `:)`